# getting a column of a specific line in bash

Tags: bash, scripting, command

I have this command :

```
id=$(xl list|egrep $Name| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

which `xl list` output something like this:

```
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs  State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  5923     8     r-----    4266.0
new_redhat9-clone                            3  1027     1     r-----    1019.6
new_redhat9                                  4  1027     1     -b----      40.1
```

Actually I want to get the `ID` of a given `Name`. This works when `Name=new_redhat9-clone` (it returns `3`) but doesnt work when `Name=new_redhat9` (it returns: `3 4`!!!!).
what is wrong?!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep searches the string pattern match. egrep new_redhat9 match with "new_redhat9" and "new_redhat9-clone". Try add whiteespace (or \t) after pattern, rewrite like this

```
id=$(xl list|egrep 'new_redhat9 '| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Comment: but I give the name through a variable! `id=$(xl list|egrep $dom_name| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)` how can do this for a variable?

Comment: try id=$(xl list|egrep "$dom_name "| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)

Comment: Add [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)  to bookmarks. It best book to learn bash scripting :)

Comment: Remark: in `'new_redhat9 '` you could also use `\s` instead of space to match both spaces and tabs; or `\b` to match word boundary. More important, you might consider to anchor your pattern at beginning of line (or same problem will appear if there is a name like `'redhat9-clone'` to grep). That would make: `egrep "^$dom_name\b"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk` instead of `egrep,tr and cut` commands,

```
id=$(xl list | awk '$1=="new_redhat9" {print $2}')
```

Awk command searches for the exact string `new_redhat9` in the first column of `xl list` output . If it finds any then then value of column2 on the corresponding record is stored to the variable `id`.

You could check the output through `echo $id` command.

If the name is stored in a variable, then give a try to the below command

```
id=$(xl list | awk -v var=$Name '$1==var {print $2}')
```

Comment: I knew this, but in fact this command is like this: id=$(xl list|egrep $dom_name| tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2) and awk doen't work as you said.

Comment: why it works? give a try to `awk -v var=$(dom_name) '$1=="var" {print $2}'`